# Is it valid to reference the limit product proof when proving the quotient proof?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Let's assume we've proven that

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$

Where $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist and are nonzero. If either are zero then we can reference a separate proof about multiplying against constants.

Anyhow, now we are faced with the notion of proving

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$$

Is it allowable to basically say "Same as the product proof except we define $h(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)}$ and use that instead?

Comment: You'd still need to prove $\lim(1/g(x))=1/(\lim g(x))$.

Comment: On a side note, I wouldn't have phrased the product theorem that way: It is apparent that the issue is when there is a $\infty$, not when there is a $0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I agree that singling out the case where one of the limits is 0 is overkill, but the hypothesis "$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists" can be interpreted to mean that it is finite.  Many elementary texts will say that if $\lim_{x\to a} = \infty$, then the limit does not exist, and instead diverges to infinity.

Comment: The reason I singled it out is because I set them equal to constants and they end up as denominators later so they cant be zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But why? If I define $h(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)}$ then it looks exactly like the product proof does it not?

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = \frac{1}{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}$?  How are you passing the limit into the denominator of the fraction?  You either have to prove that from first principles, or prove (1) that you can pass limits into continuous functions and (2) that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is a continuous function.  Since I'm not sure that you can use the second idea without circular arguments, it is probably best to stick with first principles.

Comment: I am saying $h(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)}$ so $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = \lim_{x\to a}  \frac{1}{g(x)}$

Comment: @user536260 You seem to be saying it, but refusing to prove it.

Comment: @user536260 You want to be able to say that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}$.  You can use the product law for limits to get a limit upstairs, but how do you get the limit in the denominator?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}$ and then ohhhhhh. I see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement is something like

> Suppose that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M \ne 0$, where both $L$ and $M$ are finite real numbers.  Then
>   $$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{L}{M}. $$

It is *absolutely* appropriate to use previously proved theorems in order to prove new theorems.  In this case, the result that you give is one important ingredient, i.e. we can write
$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{g(x)}, $$
then use that the limit of a product is the product of the limits in order to conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L \cdot \lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{g(x)}.
$$
This does leave one detail unresolved:  do you know how to show that
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{M}? $$
Somehow, you need to prove that this limit works out the way you want.  One way to do this is as follows:

> *Proof:* Fix $\varepsilon > 0$.  Since $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M$ and $2|M|^2 > 0$, we can use the definition of the limit to choose $\delta_1>0$ so that $$|M-g(x)| < 2|M|^2\varepsilon\tag{1}$$ for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta_1$.  By similar reasoning, we may also choose $\delta_2>0$ so that
>   $$ |g(x) - M| < |M|
> \implies -|M| < g(x) - M < |M|
> \implies |g(x)| < 2|M| \tag{2}$$
>   for all $x$ such that $|x-a| < \delta_2$.  Fix $\delta = \min\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \}$.  If $|x-a| < \delta$, then both (1) and (2) must hold, and so
>   $$ \left| \frac{1}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{M} \right|
> = \left| \frac{M - g(x)}{Mg(x)} \right|
> =  \frac{ |M - g(x)|}{|M||g(x)|}
> < \frac{2|M|^2 \varepsilon}{|M| \cdot 2|M|}
> = \varepsilon.$$
>   Therefore
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{M}. $$

With this little lemma in hand, we now have the result, namely
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
= \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)}
= \frac{L}{M}. $$
Note, however, that this intermediate step probably didn't save us much time or effort.  We could prove this directly by examining the expression
$$ \left| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{L}{M} \right|
= \frac{ |Mf(x) - Lg(x)| }{|M||g(x)|}. $$
Bounding the numerator is *slightly* more complicated, but not by much.